# Performance Improvement of the hive with SSD

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, shuffle

I'm try to use the SSD in order to improve the hive performance.
SSD is, have a high-speed random access. Taking advantage to try to change the hive to be executed in the mapreduce code.
Now my idea is to simplify or eliminate the shuffling step.
Is it possible this? If possible, Where you do change?

ps. Tell us what happens when the hive is operating, where temporary files are stored.

I do not know English well. I'm sorry.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can write your own partitioner and send the data on reducer which runs on the same node where the mapper ran.
Doing so you will never get the output file "unsplitted", so avoid the shuffling is not a good idea.

If you have a fast disk like SSD can be, you can increase the block size.
Usually the block size is computed to have the seek time no bigger than the 1% of the whole block transfer.

This will also reduce the number of the mapper used, since the number of the splits are few. Somewhat, less mapper means also less shuffling.
Using a compressed file format for the intermediate file, also speedup the work.